# Grouped products - how to add a field?

Tags: magento2, products

I have simple products inside grouped products.

I am looking for a way, so that when I add a simple product to a grouped product, I can specify Not just the quantity of the simple products but also the value of a field (for example "color").

Example:

grouped product 1:

- sku1 qty=1 color=red
- sku2 qty=2 color=blue
- sku3 qty=1 color=green

grouped product 2:

- sku4 qty=2 color=blue
- sku1 qty=2 color=green

So as you can see, in the first grouped product I want the simple product sku1 to have a red color and in the second grouped product I want the same simple product sku1 to have the color green.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

I am using magento2.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento every colour variations are treated separate product. That's why it is so handy to create the group/bundle products.

Simply go to group product create page and in the `grouped products` section, add products as you want and set the qty.
[image]

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

You will need to create configurable products with these colour variations first and then create group product. I assume you know how to create configurable products. [Learn here](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to achieve here is you're trying to add a configurable product (not simple like in your example) in a grouped product. You can't change a product attribute in a simple product (if the simple product has the color red then it will only be red). And as far as I know, natively, you can't add configurable products in group products (you might need to create an entirely new module).